# "_com_error" Can't open SQL Server Using ADO C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, database-connection, ado

I am trying to connect my C++ project to SQL Server using ADO.it goes well when checking first "hr" but error encounter when opening database on the second "if" statement, it says '`Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location`'.

i wonder what is the problem and how can i open database? or is there another way to open database?

i have already tried to change `_ConnectionPtr pConnection = NULL;` into this `_ConnectionPtr pConnection("ADODB.Connection")`.  here is my code:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;

_ConnectionPtr pConnection = NULL;
_RecordsetPtr   pRecordset = NULL;

_bstr_t strCon("Data Source=...\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True");

hr = pConnection.CreateInstance((__uuidof(Connection)));
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Error instantiating Connection objectn");
}

//Open the SQL Server connection
hr = pConnection->Open(strCon, "", "", 0);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Error Opening Database object using ADO _ConnectionPtr n");
}
```

Comment: Are you calling `CoInitialize` in your code before using COM library?

Comment: now its work, thank you